# Target [App\Http\Controllers\IndexController] is not instantiable. in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have cloned project from github and installed in my local system everything is working fine.

And i created controller through command, the controller is created but when i try to use controller function the error shows me like below.

> BindingResolutionException
>
> Target [App\Http\Controllers\SomeController] is not instantiable.
>   in Container.php (line 895)

I tried to solve this problem by running command below:

> php artisan cache:clear
>
> php artisan clear-compiled
>
> composer dump-autoload
>
> php artisan optimize
>
> php artisan config:clear

But i still got same error. Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

My controller is:

```
<?php

 namespace App\Http\Controllers;

 use Illuminate\Http\Request;

 class SomeController extends Controller
 {
  public function getIndex() {
    echo "string";
  }
 }
```

AppServiceProvider.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
 public function boot()
 {
    //
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
 }

  /**
   * Register any application services.
   *
   * @return void
  */
  public function register()
  {
      //
  }
}
```

Controller.php

```
<?php

 namespace App\Http\Controllers;

 use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
 use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
 use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
 use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
 use Carbon\Carbon;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;


protected function __construct() {

   $variable2 = "I am Data 2";
   View::share ( 'variable2', $variable2 );
} 

protected function create_permission($role_type_id,$module_id)
{
    $CheckCreatePermission = \DB::table('role_type_access')->where(['role_type_id'=> $role_type_id,'module_id'=>$module_id])->select('create')->get();
    if(!empty($CheckCreatePermission[0]))
    {
        if($CheckCreatePermission[0]->create===1)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}

protected function edit_permission($role_type_id,$module_id)
{
    $CheckEditPermission = \DB::table('role_type_access')->where(['role_type_id'=> $role_type_id,'module_id'=>$module_id])->select('edit')->get();
    if(!empty($CheckEditPermission[0]))
    {
        if($CheckEditPermission[0]->edit===1)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}

protected function delete_permission($role_type_id,$module_id)
{
    $CheckDeletePermission = \DB::table('role_type_access')->where(['role_type_id'=> $role_type_id,'module_id'=>$module_id])->select('delete')->get();
    if(!empty($CheckDeletePermission[0]))
    {
        if($CheckDeletePermission[0]->delete===1)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}

protected function view_permission($role_type_id,$module_id)
{
    $CheckViewPermission = \DB::table('role_type_access')->where(['role_type_id'=> $role_type_id,'module_id'=>$module_id])->select('view')->get();
    if(!empty($CheckViewPermission[0]))
    {
        if($CheckViewPermission[0]->view===1)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}

protected function view_all_permission($role_type_id,$module_id)
{
    $CheckLayoutPermission = \DB::table('role_type_access')
    ->join('modules', 'role_type_access.module_id', '=', 'modules.id')
    ->where(['role_type_access.role_type_id'=> $role_type_id,'role_type_access.view'=>1,'role_type_access.module_id'=>$module_id])
    ->select('role_type_access.module_id','role_type_access.view','role_type_access.create','role_type_access.edit','role_type_access.delete','modules.name','modules.label')->get();

    return $CheckLayoutPermission;

   // print_R($$CheckViewMenuPermission);
   // echo count($CheckViewMenuPermission);
   /*        if(!empty($CheckViewPermission[0]))
    {
        if($CheckViewPermission[0]->view===1)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;*/
}

public function getDownload($file_path,$file_name)
{
    //PDF file is stored under project/public/download/info.pdf
    $file= public_path().'/uploads/'.$file_path.'/'.$file_name;
    $headers = array(
              'Content-Type: application/pdf',
            );

    return \Response::download($file, $file_name, $headers);
}

public function updateTracker($tracked_date,$action)
{

    $Globaltracks = \DB::table('global_tracks')->where('tracked_date', $tracked_date)->get();
    if (count($Globaltracks) > 0) {

        \DB::table('global_tracks')
        ->where('tracked_date', $tracked_date)
        ->increment($action,1,['updated_at'=>Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString()]);

    } else {

        $Globaltracks_id = \DB::table('global_tracks')->insert(
        ['tracked_date' => $tracked_date,$action => 1,'created_at'=>Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString()]);

    }

   }


   }
```

Comment: Provide your `AppServiceProvider.php` code to check the binding way that your code followed

Comment: Have updated my question with appserviceprovider @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd

Comment: Try by making constructor of your parent controller as public instead of Protected

Answer (score 5):

Change Your Constructor Access Modifier to Public. It solve my problem.

```html
public function __construct() {

   $variable2 = "I am Data 2";
   View::share ( 'variable2', $variable2 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your `SomeController` with the below code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SomeController extends Controller
{
    public function getIndex() {
        echo "string";
    }
}
```

Comment: @V.php: Which laravel version you are using?

Comment: Im using laravel 5.4

Comment: Requested about `SomeController` where you facing the issue